# vagrant provision commands via ssh

Tags: vagrant

I want to be able to provision a vm by executing commands via ssh. I don't want to upload a shell script and execute it because that will not work on my case as my VM is a virtual appliance that has SSH support but not bash. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you would not be able to use the shell provisioner with a script file.

1. a possibility is to use *inline script*

   ```
   $script = <<SCRIPT
   echo I am provisioning...
   apt-get install -y apache2
   SCRIPT

   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
   end
   ```

This should not upload any file but should execute the script directly from ssh

2. you can run `vagrant ssh -c COMMAND` to execute command from `ssh` once the machine is provisioned so not ideal but you could script all your provisioning with this command in a script and execute this script from host once the vm is boot